# Is there a way to get charCode from an individual character?

Tags: javascript, string, char, ecmascript-6

I like the function `String.prototype.charCodeAt`, but as it is a method on `String` you have to provide an index argument. I know that Ecmascript don't handle individual characters, but is there any **"native"** way to get a charCode directly from one character? Something like `str[0].charCode()` or anything that consider a 1-length string?

Comment: What does a problem to use `"s".charCodeAt(0)` ?

Comment: @MysterX It doesn't make sense, semantically speaking. And I think it's less performatic than a teorically char implementation, since it do a kind of calc. In C, for example, we could simply use the binding name itself, it's a raw value. And last but not least, it's verbose.

Comment: There is no `Char` type in JS; your question sounds like you think there is or you want there to be, but there isn't.

Comment: @Mathletics Actually I was thinking in a way to use it purely, not like an object. For example, to verify if a char is between `'A'` and `'Z'`, something like `if(str[0] >= 65 && str[0] <= 90)` instead of `if(str.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && str.charCodeAt(0) <= 90)`

Comment: I think the *Pure OO* nature of ES makes it impossible.

Comment: From your example, you can just do `if ('A' < str[0] && str[0] < 'Z') { ... }`

Comment: @Mathletics That's a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any native way to get a charCode directly from one character?

No. As you say, EcmaScript does not deal with "one character" things specially.

If you need to deal with single characters, you could readily store them as numeric values directly, and convert them to strings only when you have sequences of them.

> Something like `str[0].charCode()`

Well, it really looks you actually want to use `str.charCodeAt(0)` here.

Comment: "Well, it really looks you actually want to use str.charCodeAt(0) here."

Either suggestion works, but the latter seems cleaner to me.

Comment: @JeffLowery What do you mean? `str[0].charCode()` does *not* work, that's why OP was asking the question.

Comment: you are right! I thought I had tested this, but I goofed somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You should define first what does it mean charCode in your case.
JS uses UTF-16 encoded strings so `charCodeAt` is a value of UTF-16 code unit at that position. Initially JS used UCS2 subset to which `charCodeAt()` had perfect sense. Not anymore with full UCS4 support encoded as UTF-16.

The only method to get real UNICODE code points (is it that charCode of yours?) from string is to use ES6 and its string enumeration feature:

```
for (let ch of str) { ch here is real UNICODE code point }
```

Note, the above may have less iterations than str.length.

And check [String.prototype.codePointAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt).

Comment: In this case, ch would be an Number or String or what?

Comment: It will be a string but this  `for (let ch of 'x\uD83D\uDE80y') {
        console.log(ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16));
    }` will give you a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.charCode = function(){
    return this.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
}
```

then you can do
`str[0].charCode();`

Comment: Sorry, I don't specified, but I'm looking for a more native way. I don't want to implement it by myself. I know how to, but it's not my intent.

Comment: Where do you get the (i) from now?

Comment: My mistake, sorry change the i by 0

Comment: That change makes even less sense.

Comment: The fiddle works, returns your char the value as hexadecimal, but you can change that.